# Open Picker inside Text Input React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, picker

I am placing age TextInput which I receive the age of user. 
I want to open picker after text input is clicked to choose age.

P.S: I am using React Native Paper UI library.

You can see my code below but appearently it doesnt working. I need sth like onPress then call function to open Picker

```
//My code for text input
        <View style={styles.searchSection}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            label="Age with Picker"
            value={this.state.age}
            onFocus={this.agePicker}
            onChangeText={this.ageHandler}
          />
        </View>

//My code for picker function
  agePicker = () => {
    return (
      <Picker
        selectedValue={this.state.language}
        style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
          this.setState({ language: itemValue })
        }
      >
        <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
        <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
      </Picker>
    );
  };
```